Why does GetAsyncKeyState registers CTRL when pressing ALT
I am currently using GetAsyncKeyState to register key presses in a csharp program.
The issue I'm running into is that when pressing right Alt (RMenu / vKey 165), the program also registers a right Control press (RControlKey / vKey 162).
I'm running a for loop to check every vKey integer of the method like this :
for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++)
{
    short keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
    if(keyState < 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

I tried filtering the RControl key out, however I'd like to also detect this one.
Am I missing something and is there a way to work around it ?

I think the issue is how you are checking if the key is pressed.
According to the documentation, you should compare the most significant bit. Try this instead:
Import the function in this manner:
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys ArrowKeys);

Then you use a binary AND operator to check if the most significant digit is set on the value returned by the imported function:
for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++)
{
    var key = (Keys)i;
    bool isKeyDown = (GetAsyncKeyState(key) & 0x8000) > 0; 
    if (isKeyDown)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} => {key}");
    }
}

The output, when the right alt key is pressed:
18 => Menu 
165 => RMenu 

You see both because from the list of keys, 18 indicates "The ALT key" and
165 is a more specific value that indicates "The right ALT key."
Similarly, pressing the right control key produces this output:
17 => ControlKey
163 => RControlKey


This works for similar cases like other Control/Shift keys but this still weirdly outputs
"
18 => Menu
162 => LControlKey
165 => RMenu
"

@NicolasGrardDaf No, it doesn't. I tested it myself before I posted it. If it's doing this for you, something else is going on, either in the rest of your code, or physically with your keyboard.

Well I definitely have the same code after copy pasting it. The only difference is that I run it in a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. I also just tested it with the Windows virtual keyboard and it stills outputs the four keys in this exact order : ControlKey, Menu, LControlKey, RMenu.

@NicolasGrardDaf have you checked the function import? Make sure it matches.

Yeah I checked and it matches. I also just tried in a simple Console Application to see if something about Forms Apps was intefering but the result was sadly the same. This is really weird...

Question for both of you - in your keyboard layout, is the right key labelled Alt or Alt Gr? I suspect the answer is different between the two of you and why you're seeing different outcomes.

(Easiest way to check what your layout says, rather than the physical keycaps, is to bring up the on-screen keyboard)

Bringing up the virtual keyboard, the label is Alt Gr for me. I forgot to say that I'm using a "french keyboard" (Which right now seems like the most logical source of the issue of not having the same output)
